# VueJS not picking up data passed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm very new to VueJS so expect this is very much a me problem but hoping for some guidance.

I have a Vue instance the person object in data contains some predefined data but I'm adding to the object when it's mounted. For whatever reason I cant understand it's not updating the DOM with the data inserted when mounted. I've checked the vue app and can confirm the person being added on the mounted method is being added correctly.

```js
    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      people: {
        Dave: {'Age': 30, 'Plays': 5}
      }
    },

    mounted: function() {
      this.people['Rob'] = {'Age': 22, 'Plays': 24};
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(person, key) in people">
      {{ key }}: {{ person.Age }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have a feeling this is either a Vue gotcha or I'm doing something really stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Instead you should be doing it like this:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  people: {
    Dave: {'Age': 30, 'Plays': 5}
  }
},

mounted: function() {
  this.$set(this.people, 'Rob', Object.assign({}, { 'Age': 22, 'Plays': 24}));
 }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/8t1nj410/)

I also recommed you go through [array change caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) so you do not face any problems in the future

Comment: Thank you, I assumed I was doing something wrong. I'll take a read over these now.

Comment: @Paradigm happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

Or use a hook that fires before the element is mounted.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: {
      Dave: {'Age': 30, 'Plays': 5}
    }
  },

  created: function() {
    this.people['Rob'] = {'Age': 22, 'Plays': 24};
  }
});
```

Comment: But should the v-for not be reactive? When there are additional items added to the data it should automatically update the list as far as I know.

Comment: When the element is mounted you need to use Vue's $set or $delete methods to add or remove objects in your people model.

Or use any hooks that fire before the element is mounted.